# shows undefined variable when changing the variable name

Tags: laravel

In my controller page I am trying to return all the data from mode to view. I have kept all the data in a variable and passed on to the view page. When I keep the variable name as `$post` I am getting error:

```
Undefined variable: post (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lsapp\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php)
```

Controller Page

```
// PostController.php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $post = Post::all();   
        return view('posts.index')-> with('posts', $post);
    }
    //remaining code blocks
```

view page code

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<h1>this is index page.</h1>
@if(count($post) > 1)
    <h2>testing</h2>

@else
    <p>No Data</p>
@endif

@endsection
```

When I change the variable name as $posts it works fine. Why does I have to keep same variable name as posts first parameter?

```
return view('posts.index')-> with('posts', $posts);  // it works fine
```

Comment: It is `$posts` not `$post` so use `@if(count($posts) > 1)
`

Comment: @C2486 thats what I am asking, why can't I use variable name as `$post` ?

Comment: then use `-> with('post', $post);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Becouse in with method you pass `with('variableName', $variable')` and in view you can use `$variableName` variable

Change your controller

```
 return view('posts.index')-> with('posts', $posts);
```

And view

```
@if(count($posts) > 1)
```

Or you can change your controller

```
 return view('posts.index')-> with('post', $posts);
```

And view

```
@if(count($post) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not my question, I want to know why can't I use the variable name as `$post` or any other variable name.

Comment: becouse in with method you pass `with('variableName', $variable'` and in view you can use `$variableName` variable

Answer (score 4):

As you are sending your variable to view as `$posts` here:

```
return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $post);
```

Use `@if(count($post) > 1)` in your view **posts.index**.

If you want to use `$post` as your variable in view, send it as `->with('post', $post);`

Comment: Unclear what you want to say, Please check variable name again

Comment: see `->with('posts', $post);` he is sending it to view as **'posts'**

Answer (score 3):

if you go to the

> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php

You will find this method. In This class you can clearly see that these values are associated with view to render.

```
public function with($key, $value = null)
{
    if (is_array($key)) {
        $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $key);
    } else {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

If you do not want to use this here is an alternative.

```
    return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
```